# Any trick to solve this optimization problem?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm relatively new to solving optimization problems using Mathematica. I have an optimization problem but Mathematica does not seem to be able to solve it. I have tried all sorts of way to re-write it equivalently. The one mentioned in this question seems to be the simplest form of all that I was able to find.

Are there any tricks that can be used to solve this problem?

```
Minimize[{(c n2)/m2^2+m2/n2,1 < n2 <= n, 1 < m2 <= m}, {n2,m2}]
```

Comment: If $c>0$, then the estimate from below is $2\sqrt{\frac {c\,n2} {m2^2}\frac {m2} {n2}}\ge 2\sqrt {\frac c {m}}.$

Comment: Are you sure that a minimum exists inside your region? Is it possible that the minimum is always on the boundary. Try to give numerical values to c,n,m and make a 3D plot using e.g. Plot3D, to get a feeling what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it using the Lagrange multipliers, introducing some slack variables (e1,e2,e3,e4) to handle the inequalities, assuming first to simplify c > 0,(c^2)  as follows:

```
f = c^2 x/y^2 + y/x;
L = f + l1 (x - 1 - e1^2) + l2 (n - x - e2^2) + l3 (y - 1 - e3^2) + l4 (m - y - e4^2)
grad = Grad[L, {x, y, l1, l2, l3, l4, e1, e2, e3, e4}];
sols = Solve[grad == 0, {x, y, l1, l2, l3, l4, e1, e2, e3, e4}];
res = {f, x, y, l1, l2, l3, l4, e1^2, e2^2, e3^2, e4^2} /. sols;
res0 = Union[res];
MatrixForm[res0]
```

Now in res0 we have the f values at the diverse stationary points as well as the values for e1^2,e2^2,e3^2,e4^2 that should be non negative to be feasible. Here when ek = 0 means that the k constraint is active. We can proceed in the same way in the case of -c^2.

We can further reduce this set to

```
res1 = {res0[[2]], res0[[5]], res0[[6]], res0[[8]], res0[[9]], res0[[11]], res0[[13]], res0[[14]]};
MatrixForm[res1]
```

NOTE

From the results obtained we can observe that the extrema are always at the boundary.

Comment: Cesareo: +1. The verification of the case `c=1;m=2;n=3;` confirms your result. However, it is difficult to find out the optimal values from `res0`. Maybe, the evaluation of the parameters and then the direct use of `Minimize` are more convenient.